# Strawberry Perl module installation issues

Tags: perl, module

Following an equipment 'upgrade' at work, which is a Windows environment, I  had to reinstall Perl. ActiveState never worked and I was able to install Strawberry, which fortunately comes with some necessary modules included, such as Excel parsers and writers. The problem is when I try to add additional needed modules. As I understand there are 2 ways to do this: Either download the tarball and build it manually or use cpan.

The first solution requires `gmake`  which is disallowed/blocked  by group policy

cpan also fails:

```
>cpan install Tk
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.52) Fetching with LWP: http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz LWP failed with code[407] message[Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )]

Proxy authentication needed! (Note: to permanently configure username and password run o conf proxy_user your_username o conf proxy_pass your_password )
```

I also read somewhere that ppm build also works with strawberry, but I have been unable to find ppds.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for setting a proxy username and password?

Comment: Strawberry Perl also comes with `cpanm`, can you try if it works?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, SP uses gmake too, doesn't it? That said, it should come with gmake. (Not sure if AP comes with it. It used to be that it would install the necessary tool automatically.)

Comment: run cpan, `o conf init /proxy/`, fill in the prompts, then retry.

Comment: Using the cpan shell won't get you around the need to compile modules that contain XS code (which Tk does). Strawberry Perl ships with everything you need to do so, but that won't help if gmake is blocked from running. It's crazy to block gmake in a shop that does any sort of software development.